# Compare two fields value get large value another field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

```
    <select  name="days"   required="required">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Duration</option>
                <option value="7 ">7 </option>
                <option value="14 ">14 </option>
                <option value="21 ">21 </option>
                <option value="28 ">28 </option>
            </select>

    <select  name="days2"   required="required">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Duration</option>
                <option value="7 ">7 </option>
                <option value="14 ">14 </option>
                <option value="21 ">21 </option>
                <option value="28 ">28 </option>
            </select>

            <input  name="result" type="text"  placeholder="Show Large Duration" / >
```

??????????????????????

Select two option get large value in Result field

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. If you search a bit it should not be that hard to find an answer that works

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you want, I really don't get it

Comment: @Jordy: put the `max` of `days` and `days2` in `result`.

Comment: Thanks @Lain! Then we'll still need the JS/jQuery code though

Comment: @Jordy. That is what he wants you to provide *Please Solve this problem* :-)

Comment: @EchoOne, you might wanna read some documentation, I bet you can find lots of similar questions on SO as well

Comment: @EchoOneDairy Please edit your question, dont post code in the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:
//html

```
<select  id="days"  onchange="val(this)" required="required">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Duration</option>
                <option value="7 ">7 </option>
                <option value="14 ">14 </option>
                <option value="21 ">21 </option>
                <option value="28 ">28 </option>
            </select>

    <select  id="days2"   onchange="val(this)" required="required">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Duration</option>
                <option value="7 ">7 </option>
                <option value="14 ">14 </option>
                <option value="21 ">21 </option>
                <option value="28 ">28 </option>
            </select>
            <input  id="result" type="text"  placeholder="Show Large Duration" / >
```

//JS

```
const x = document.getElementById("days");
const y = document.getElementById("days2");
const result = document.getElementById("result");


function val(){
 
  if((x.value !== null && x.value !== '') && (y.value !== null && y.value !== '')){
    if(isFinite(x.value) && isFinite(y.value)){
      result.value = (Number(x.value) > Number(y.value)) ? x.value : y.value;
    }else{
      result.value = 'no value'
    }
  }
  
}
```